# Gallery application replacement for adding text based Photo Notes

Tags: gallery, images, exif

The Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo stock Gallery application has (and other models do too) an option to set a Photo Note when you're viewing a picture. When you select it the picture rotates via some OpenGL animation, and you can scribble on its back. But the space is limited, whereas attaching a note using the virtual keyboard would make it possible to enter a virtually infinite string of characters inside the EXIF data. Beasies the fact that I'm not even sure how to view the scribbled notes (or EXIF data!) once you transfer the picture to the PC (perhaps someone can explain), this feature would be really useful.

Anyone know how I can make use of the feature I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of photo apps that will let you edit exif data on the android.  This one specifically does the data: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teapps.exiftageditor, some do other pieces of editing, some sort your files for you, etc, etc.  Take a look around for one that works well with your particular image work flow.

Wikipedia has a nice roundup for PC/desktop meta data editors here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_metadata_editors. Your choice will of course depend on your PC, budget, and needs.